# listener must be a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

flabbergasted by this one

```
    var integrantMessage = function (msg) {
      if (msg.info === 'integrant-ready') {
        integrantsFromParentProcess.push(msg.data);
          if (sumanUtils.checkForEquality(integrants, integrantsFromParentProcess)) {
            process.removeListener(integrantMessage);
            integrantsReady = true;
            cb(null);
          }
        }
        else if (msg.info === 'integrant-error') {
          process.removeListener(integrantMessage);
          cb([msg.data]);
        }
    };

    process.on('message', integrantMessage);
    process.send({type: constants.runner_message_type.INTEGRANT_INFO, msg: integrants});
```

on the process.removeListener() lines, I get the error:

```
TypeError: listener must be a function
            at process.removeListener (events.js:276:15)
```

anyone have any idea why that would happen? I checked and it is actually a function, not sure what is going on here. A function declaration also yields the same error.

I can guarantee, when integrantMessage is called, it is called asynchronously (in the next tick of the event loop).

Comment: it should take two parameters [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_event_removelistener)

Comment: ah yes, dynamic languages LOL

Comment: this is probably the 5th time I have made this mistake over the last 3 months

Answer (score 0):

```
process.removeListener();
```

or generally

```
new EventEmitter().removeListener()
```

takes two args, not one

as per the docs

https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_event_removelistener